# page break after certain tables

Tags: php, html, css

my problem is :
I have a page with several html tables that I want to print. Some tables have many rows, other have not. What I want to do is print the first and the second table (the big ones) in seperate pages and the rest of them (small ones) two per page. How can I put a page-break where I want to? 
I tried

```
<style>
@media print
{
table {page-break-after: left}
}
</style>
```

but this puts a page break after each table, something I do not want.

Anyone can help???
Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would put the rule into a class, and apply the class to each table.

```
@media print
 {
   table.break {page-break-after: left}

 }
```

And HTML:

```
<table class="break">
```

Comment: Thanks, i amended for a div, using  div.break, Thanks!